# What does "or" in function-parameters in python mean?

Tags: python, django

I was just watching a tutorial and the following pattern appeared:

```
#some code
function(variable1 or variable2)
#more code
```

I'm really wondering what this `or` means in this case.

**Could someone explain the purpose of `or`in function parameters?**
Thanks for your help and stay healthy!

Comment: It evaluates the truthiness of the first operand. If it is true, it uses the left operand, if false, it uses the right one.

Comment: It doesn't matter in what context it is used, `a or b` always means the same thing (`a if a else b`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `x or y` roughly corresponds to `x if x else y`, which basically means use `x` if it has a truthy value (e.g. not zero, a non-empty list, a string of at least length 1, True, not None, etc.), otherwise use `y`.

So calling `function(Variable1 or Variable2)` is roughly like calling `function(Variable1 if Variable1 else Variable2)`

Answer (score 1):

Expression with parameter `or` returns first occurence of the operand, which gives `True`.

Example:

```
>>> x = 'some_string'

>>> y = 'other_string'

>>> z = ''

>>> x or y
: 'some_string'

>>> y or x
: 'other_string'

>>> x or z
: 'some_string'

>>> z or x
: 'some_string'
```